# create a stored procedure if it doesnt exist using a ddl in db2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, procedure-definition, db2-9.5, extended-stored-procedure

My requirements are,

I want to create a ddl script which will check if a stored procedure exists on DB, if yes then drop it and recreate it.

What I tried is,

```
IF EXISTS (select procname into Migration_procname from sysibm.sysprocedures where procname like 'GIAM_PRIVILEGE_MIGRATION') THEN 
    DROP PROCEDURE ITIMUSER.GIAM_PRIVILEGE_MIGRATION;
ELSE
CREATE PROCEDURE ITIMUSER.GIAM_PRIVILEGE_MIGRATION()
SPECIFIC ITIMUSER.GIAM_PRIVILEGE_MIGRATION
LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN 

......
......
update/select statements
......

END
@
```

which didn't work.
so I even tried with creating another procedure which is doing same task still no success.

The error message was

> DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it returned: SQL0104N An unexpected token "IF EXISTS (select procname" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT". Expected tokens may include: "". SQLSTATE=42601

Any pointers will be helpful.

NOTE: I am using DB2/LUW 9.5

Answer (score 1):

IBM Added The **OR REPLACE** option in version 7.1

So your code should work like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ITIMUSER.GIAM_PRIVILEGE_MIGRATION()
SPECIFIC ITIMUSER.GIAM_PRIVILEGE_MIGRATION
LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN 

......
......
update/select statements
......

END
```

Comment: The OP uses DB2 for LUW 9.5

Comment: I am using DB LUW 9.5 which doesnt have 'OR REPLACE' feature, that is introduced in 9.7

Answer (score 1):

In DB2 9.5 for LUW, create or replace does not work. It is added in 9.7.
For 9.5+ compatibility, which my shop still has to maintain, I have created the following approach.
Essentially, I create a utility stored procedure that will determine whether or not the other stored procedure exists or not, and then drops it conditionally so no error messages will appear.
Then, I call that to drop the stored procedure I want to drop.
Then, I clean up after myself since we can't reliably track where this has or has not been created.

NOTE: I'm currently working on refining this. It was done in a hurry and can obviously be simplified to use fewer variables.
I'd also like to base it on SYSCAT.PROCEDURES, as in the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCSCHEMA = CURRENT_SCHEMA AND PROCNAME = 'MYPROC'
```

So, here's the actual SP:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR !

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Drop_Proc_If_Exists  (IN v_ProcName varchar(255))
Drop_Proc_If_Exists: BEGIN
    DECLARE V_EXISTENCE     CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N';
    DECLARE V_FOUND_COUNT   INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE V_DROP_STMT     VARCHAR(255);

    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    INTO    V_FOUND_COUNT
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINENAME = v_ProcName;

    IF (V_FOUND_COUNT > 0) THEN
        SET V_DROP_STMT = 'DROP PROCEDURE ' || v_ProcName;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_DROP_STMT;
    END IF;

END Drop_Proc_If_Exists
!


CALL SP_Drop_Proc_If_Exists  ('DROP_FK_CONSTRAINTS')
!

DROP PROCEDURE SP_Drop_Proc_If_Exists
!

--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```